# Batch : extract some characters of a string

Tags: batch, string, findstr

How can I extract alphanumeric characters only from a string?

Example :   `b:lbalbqsd1287/;:!,` gives `blbalbqsd1287`

Is it possible with `findstr`?

Comment: `findstr` works **on** lines, not **in** lines and it never extract sth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can somehow be possible to do this in batch. I don't know how and I'm sure it's painful, not maintainable and ugly. But, as an alternative you can use a vbscript to do the job (also built-in and must be available in every OS).
I wrote this little guy here for your pleasure :)

```
Option Explicit

Dim sInput, sOutput
sInput = "b:lbalbqsd1287/;:!,"
sOutput = RegEXP_VBS(sInput) 
Call MsgBox (sOutput)
 
Function RegEXP_VBS(sIn)
Dim oREGEXP, oResult, oMatch

    Set oREGEXP = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp") 
    oREGEXP.IgnoreCase = False
    oREGEXP.MultiLine = False 
    oREGEXP.Global = True
    oREGEXP.Pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]"

    Set oResult = oREGEXP.Execute(sIn)
    For Each oMatch in oResult
        RegEXP_VBS = RegEXP_VBS & oMatch.Value
    Next 

End Function
```

As you can see it uses regular expression for the job which you can change fairly easy if the scope of search-string changes.